# Decomposition of disjoint cycles

Tags: permutations

Work out the decomposition in disjoint cycles for the following.

a)  (14)(12345) = (15)(234)

b)  (12)(2345) = (12345)

c)  (12)(23)(34) = (14)(24)

d)  (13)(1234)(13) = (143)(2)

Can anyone tell me if the parts a) and b) are correct? And can anyone please help me with part c) and d)? I get confuse on the second cycle.

Thank you

Comment: They can't both be correct: one uses right-to-left composition, whereas the other uses left-to-right composition.

Comment: Usually it is meant from right to left, whence a) were correct (in the first edit), and b) becomes $(12345)$.